# How to align matrices when dealing with arrays of different shapes (using python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have the following arrays (vectors):
l=[[0.483, 0.923], [0.781, 0.188], [0.446, 0.564, 0.796]]

I wrote the following lines of code to compute the cosine similarity between the vectors, and got this error message: ValueError: matrices are not aligned.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as LA
l=[[0.483, 0.923], [0.781, 0.188], [0.446, 0.564, 0.796]]
cx = lambda a, b : round(np.inner(a, b)/(LA.norm(a)*LA.norm(b)), 2)
for v in l:
   for y in l:
    cosine=cx(v,y)
    print cosine
```

On adjusting the arrays to equal length (l=[[0.483, 0.923], [0.781, 0.188], [0.446, 0.564]]), my code worked fine.

The issue now is how can I make my code work without adjusting the shape of the arrays? (ie how to align the matrices).  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What do these numbers represent? Is `[0.4, 0.9]` similar to `[0.4, 0.9, 10**6]`? is it similar to `[0.4, 10**6, 0.9]`?

Comment: The numbers are vectors (term frequencies). [0.4, 0.9] represents a text document, likewise the others. To answer your question, [0.4, 0.9] may be similar to [0.4, 0.9, 10**6] depending on the weight of 10**6.

Comment: The problem is, when the matrices are aligned ie [0.4, 0.9] and [0.8, 0.3], their similarity can be computed.But when the vectors in any of the arrays is more in number than the other ie [0.4, 0.9] and [0.8, 0.3, 0.7], the issue of alignment comes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using cosine similarity, it appears there should be a geometric interpretation for `a` and `b`. (The cosine similarity is finding the cosine of the angle between two vectors).

A vector of length 2 can be thought of as existing in the `xy-plane`, and a vector of length 3 can be thought of as existing in `xyz-space`.
So the vector `[0.4, 0.9]` in the plane can be thought of as being the 3-dimensional vector `[0.4, 0.9, 0]` in `xyz-space`.

If that's reasonable, then taking the inner product between a 2D-vector and a 3D-vector is equivalent to taking the inner product after simply dropping the third component (since multiplication of anything by 0 is 0).

Thus you could define `cx` this way:

```
def cx(a, b) :
    a, b = (a, b) if len(a) < len(b) else (b, a)
    b = b[:len(a)]
    try:
        assert any(a)
        assert any(b)
    except AssertionError:
        print('either a or b is zero')
        # return 0  or 
        # raise 
    return round(np.inner(a, b)/(LA.norm(a)*LA.norm(b)), 2)
```

---

You'll get better performance by filling in the missing values in `l` so it can be made into a NumPy array. Then you can apply NumPy operations to *the whole array* at once and eliminate the double Python `for-loops`:

```
def cosine_similarity(l):
    inner = np.einsum('ij,kj -> ik', l, l)
    norm = np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij -> i', l*l))
    return inner/(norm*norm[:, np.newaxis])

def to_3d(l):
    return np.array([row+[0]*(3-len(row)) for row in l])

np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
print(cosine_similarity(to_3d(l)))
```

yields

```
[[ 1.    0.66  0.66]
 [ 0.66  1.    0.53]
 [ 0.66  0.53  1.  ]]
```

Compared with

```
def cx(a, b) :
    a, b = (a, b) if len(a) < len(b) else (b, a)
    b = b[:len(a)]
    return round(np.inner(a, b)/(LA.norm(a)*LA.norm(b)), 2)

def using_cx():
    for v in l:
       for y in l:
        cosine=cx(v,y)
```

timeit shows an 11x increase in speed:

```
In [90]: %timeit using_cx()
1000 loops, best of 3: 380 us per loop

In [91]: %timeit cosine_similarity(to_3d(l))
10000 loops, best of 3: 32.6 us per loop
```

The computation is still quadratic -- which it will always be if you wish to compare each possible pair of rows in `l`. But it is faster because the NumPy functions are written in C, which tends to be faster than equivalent code calling Python functions in Python loops.

Comment: many thanks to you. your explanation is spot-on, and the code works fine now. However, when I tried it on a larger data set, in between the output, I got this message: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide.

Comment: That means either `a` or `b` must be the zero vector. I'll put a check in the code to help you debug/handle the problem.

Comment: thanks for the deburging. The current problem I'm facing is that the computation is quadratic. I tried the code on a data set of 100 vectors (documents), and the output was 100 x 100=10,0000 values(cosine distance). I was actually expecting 100 values.

Comment: I have a feeling this might work: take the first vector in the list and compute its cosine distance from remaining 99 vectors, as each value in the list (vector) represent one document. In so doing, the cosine distance between the first vector and the rest (each of the 99) can be determined.